# How to resolve Oracle missing expression in JSP?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

While executing the below code in JSP, I am getting this error

> (ORA-00936: missing expression)

I have checked the whole query statement several times but can't figure out where the error is. All the single and double quotes are closed.

```
else if(desig.equals("Project Manager"))
                {
                  String qry="select fname from emp_master where emp_id="+
                      ("select eno from emp_digital where user_id='"+uname+"'");
                  ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(qry);
                  rs1.next();
                  name=rs1.getString(1);
               }
```

Can someone please help me out? I am running this JSP.
I have checked all the questions here but didnot get any answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use brackets for nested select `select t from table where id = (select ...)`

Comment: Can you specify the details about those two database table.

Comment: 1. don't use scriptlets: put this code in a Java class; 2. Learn prepared stateents: this code is broken if uname contains a single quote, and open for SQL injection attacks; 3. post the complete stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery should be in parenthesis like this:

```
String qry="select fname from emp_master where emp_id="+
                  "(select eno from emp_digital where user_id='"+uname+"')";
```

And you should definitely have a look at `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1):

looks to me like the error would be in this section: `("select eno from emp_digital where user_id='"+uname+"'")`

I'd have re-written it as something like:

```
("select eno from emp_digital where user_id=" + uname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...you should write "(" and ")" with in the quotes in query string.

```
  else if(desig.equals("Project Manager")) 
  {
    String qry="select fname from emp_master where emp_id="+"(select eno from emp_digital where user_id='"+uname+"')";

    ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(qry); 
    rs1.next(); 
    name=rs1.getString(1); 
  }
```